# Swift 5 JSONDecoder decode JSON with field name having a space eg "post title": "Hello World"

Tags: json, swift, swift5, jsondecoder

I'm currently using JSONDecoder to parse json into objects with Swift 5. I'm just realizing now that part of the JSON is bad JSON. It has a field name with a space: "Post Title". I'm not sure why it is like this, and I'm aware it is bad practice for JSON to be setup like this, but there's not much I can do on the JSON side. Is there a way to use JSON decoder to get that field as is?

I've researched this a ton, but since it is an issue with bad json, I'm not finding much online other than creating a custom decoder/deserializer (which I'm trying to avoid).

JSON:

```
{
    "Post Title":"Hello World"
}
```

Struct:

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    var PostTitle: String
}
```

Decoder:

```
let jsonObject = try jsonDecoder.decode(Post.self, from: responseData)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For custom keys, use `CodingKeys` to match JSON keys.

```swift
struct Post : Codable {

    var PostTitle: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case PostTitle = "Post Title"
    }
}
```

**Note:** you should use lowercased starting letter for variables.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Comment: It is mentioned in the documentation to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types 
I need to focus on documentation then it is better to post on stackoverflow.